# Switching from Ubuntu Desktop to Ubuntu Tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lenovo, desktop-environments, tablet, touchscreen

I have been considering buying a Lenovo Yoga 11S (I am aware that I will have to recompile the kernel due to the wireless driver). My main concern is having a good experience in both laptop mode and tablet mode. I am wondering whether I can write a script that will be triggered when the hinge goes past 180° that will switch the interface from Ubuntu desktop to Ubuntu tablet.

My main questions are:

- Is it possible to have Ubuntu tablet installed as a DE?
- Is it possible to run Ubuntu tablet fullscreen in a window?

Answer (score 2):

1. There is only Ubuntu, it's the same OS on tablet, desktop, phone, server, and cloud.  That's convergence.  So to answer your question about whether Ubuntu will run on your Lenovo Yoga 11S, that answer is yes.
2. While it does not ship this way out of the box, there is a package that surfaces the position sensor (as well as the 9DOF and ambient light sensors) into userspace, and that can be scripted to hook into other functionality such as rotating the display, disabling the physical keyboard, and enabling the on-screen keyboard.  I have a Yoga, I have done this.
3. You may want to experiment with the Unity 8 shell, since most applications built for X11 and the Unity 7 shell work poorly with a touch-only device.
4. Work is ongoing in Ubuntu to make convertible devices work smoothly out of the box, but don't expect it delivered in 16.10.  Maybe (no promises) 17.04, so keep on top of the current -dev version if you're willing to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Unity 8, in it's current incarnation, is the tablet UI that we have seen. In it's current development state, it can be installed on desktop, with instructions [here](https://unity.ubuntu.com/getinvolved/development/unity8/).

I didn't end up getting the Lenovo Yoga, so I can't tell anyone interested how it is.